# Proving Inequality Involving Sums and Products of Variables in a Probabilistic Analysis

Tags: probability, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I'm exploring a probabilistic analysis problem where I have variables (or, probabilities) $x_1,\ldots, x_n \in (0,1)$ in the range $(0,1)$ satisfying $\sum^n_{i=1} x_i \in (0,1)$. I aim to prove the inequality: $$\frac{1-\prod^{k+1}_{i = 1} (1-x_i)}{\sum^{k+1}_{i=1} x_i} \leq \frac{1-\prod^{k}_{i = 1} (1-x_i)}{\sum^k_{i=1} x_i}.$$
For all $k \in \{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$. This inequality essentially suggests that augmenting the denominator by adding $x_{k+1}$ to the denominator while multiplying the second term in the nominator by $(1-x_{k+1})$ overall can only decrease the overall expression.

I've attempted to employ the arithmetic/geometric mean inequality, but I haven't succeeded so far. Can anyone provide insights or alternative approaches that could help in proving this inequality?

Comment: Just cross multiply and keep on simplifying terms. You'd end up with $ \frac{1}{ \prod (1-x_i) } \geq 1 + \sum x_i $ which is true using the binomial theorem.

Comment: How does it follow from the binomial theorem?

Comment: Please show your work and where you're stuck. EG Do you know what is $ \frac{1}{ 1 - x_i } $ via the negative binomial theorem? $\quad$ In fact, we don't need the extent of that theorem. There's a simpler proof of that final line. So, please show what you've tried, and why you can't push through.

Comment: I reached the expression $\frac{1}{\prod (1-x_i)} \geq 1+\sum x_i$. From there I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: Please show your work of reaching the expression. This site closes questions for "no/little context given".

Comment: Sure, a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

For ease of notation / laziness, let $ S_K = \sum_{i=1}^{K} x_i, P_K = \prod_{i=1}^K (1 - x_i) , $.

- Cross multiplying, WTS $ S_k - S_k P_{k+1} \leq S_{k+1} - S_{k+1} P_k $
- Shifting and grouping terms, WTS $x_{k+1} P_k + S_kP_k [ 1 - ( 1-x_{k+1}) ] \leq x_{k+1}$.
- Dividing by $x_{k+1}$, WTS $P_k ( 1 + S_k) \leq 1$.  -> OP stated in comments that they arrived at this step.
- This follows from $ \frac{1}{1 -x_i} \geq 1 + x_i $ for $ x_ i \in (0,1 )$.

> $$\frac{1}{ P_k} \geq \prod ( 1 + x_i ) \geq 1 + \sum x_i + \sum_{i\neq j} x_i x_j + \ldots  \geq 1 + \sum x_i.$$